# Marionette CollectionView re-render when a model is removed from the collection

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I figured out my problem, but I would like to know *why*, so that I may (hopefully) understand Marionette/backbone better.

**Problem** The code below does update the view when an item is removed:

```
var MainView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: "#sample-template",
    events :{
        "click #remove" : "remove"
    },
    remove: function(){            
        this.trigger("property:remove", this.model);
    }
});
var CollectionView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    itemView: MainView,
    initialize: function(){
        this.on("itemview:property:remove", function(view, model){
            alert(this.collection.length);
            this.collection.remove(model);
            alert(this.collection.length);
        });
    }
});
```

[A JsFiddle to view in all its glory](http://jsfiddle.net/mlsteeves/ALLse/2/)

**The fix** The code below does update the view as expected:

```
var MainView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: "#sample-template",
    triggers :{
        "click #remove" : "property:remove"
    },
});

var CollectionView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    itemView: MainView,
    initialize: function(){
        this.on("itemview:property:remove", function(view, model){
            alert(this.collection.length);
            this.collection.remove(view.model);
            alert(this.collection.length);
        });
    }
});
```

[The jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mlsteeves/ALLse/3/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Backbone.View` defines a method called `remove` that removes a view from the DOM. Your first example overrides that method.

If you rename `remove` to something like `removeIt` the name collision disappears and the code works as expected. For what it's worth, I think the second approach is preferable for this type of situation anyway.

Comment: That is it. I love how the dumb things mess you up. 

And yes, the second option is cleaner. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone who comes across this, keep in mind that Marionette 2.x changed itemview to childview. Tripped me up a bit. Cheers!